# React Native why is an app.js from another app being loaded?

Tags: react-native

When I run

```
react-native run-android
```

My app loads up and I'm immediately greeted with a red screen

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RNPushNotification.getInitialNotification')
```

Which is fine and all EXCEPT for I don't have `RNPushNotification` in this project at all. That said, it IS part of another project I'm working on.

Further into the error screen the stack trace references `App.js:24:27` and when I click on it I'm taken to the `App.js` from my other project!!

I've double checked all files / settings and am stumped as to why this is happening. I even went as far as building directly from Android Studio and still this error persists. Why would this happen and better yet how can I re-correct?

** EDIT **

```
$ react-native run-android

...

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 12s
45 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 44 up-to-date
Running /Users/Jackson/.android/platform-tools/adb -s e362dc15 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
Starting the app on e362dc15 (/Users/Jackson/.android/platform-tools/adb -s e362dc15 shell am start -n com.workingproject/com.workingproject.MainActivity)...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.workingproject/.MainActivity }
```

`com.workingproject` is the correct project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The give away was in the output

```
JS server already running.
```

Apparently I never closed my JS Server window when I switched projects so this project was connected to the JS server for my last project, hence the mixup.